# Upgrade php to php 7.0 on Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos, php-7

I am working on Mac OS X with Yosmite 10.10.5 installed.

I need to upgrade my PHP version to be 7.0 to support some features on a web application I am working on.

I used this command

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.0
```

and now when I run `php -v`

I get an error

> -bash: /usr/local/bin/php: No such file or director

I think I need to add the new php to my PATH but I don't know where I can find the new PHP files or how to add it to PATH.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where is new php located?

Comment: this is part of my question

Comment: Try using Homebrew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you've already successfully installed the PHP 7.0. Just check it in PHP INFO Tab after running your server. (e.g. http://localhost:8888/MAMP/).

Alternatively you can run

```
phpInfo();
```

command in any existing page and test.

php-osx doesn't overwrite the php binaries installed by Apple, but installs everything in /usr/local/php5. The new php binary is therefore in /usr/local/php5/bin/php.

You can also adjust your PATH do include that directory, eg. write into your ~/.profile file the following

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```